# Create an Auto-Complete in elastic search

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

I want to use ElasticSearch to index mobile apps data.
So my documents are GooglePlay packages of the mapping:

```
 "application": {
            "_id": {
                "path": "code"
            },
            "properties": {
                "code": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                },
                "category": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "updated_as_of": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                }
            }
        }
```

I then want to create a "suggestion" as someone starts typing the name of an app.
So, if my documents are:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "apps",
    "_type": "application",
    "_id": "com.maxmpz.poweramp.skins.ironyellowmetalmachine",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "category": "Music & Audio",
      "updated_as_of": "25-11-2014 12:07:58",
      "name": "Poweramp skin STEEL I. Yellow",
      "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.poweramp.skins.ironyellowmetalmachine",
      "code": "com.maxmpz.poweramp.skins.ironyellowmetalmachine",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh6.ggpht.com/a0Osb7RQcgjyNzoK22i2V6kndab7KWis3HZ9cwXqvCFNtQNDOUMWhSSl8IcJYsL2OA=w300"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "apps",
    "_type": "application",
    "_id": "it.medieval.blueftp",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "category": "Communication",
      "updated_as_of": "30-11-2014 15:27:39",
      "name": "Bluetooth File Transfer",
      "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp",
      "code": "it.medieval.blueftp",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh6.ggpht.com/emp6MlSfqJhZBlhsU4hbQN2jJnXszciwb1QSumuUzl1zWj2aBYoZZHe_e9td8aOCb_U=w300"
    }
  }
]
```

As the user types `ski` I want to suggest `Poweramp skin STEEL I. Yellow`.

I tried just using a `match` query, but this only work for whole words, and fails capitalization.
So `"match":"skin"` works, but `"match":"sKIn"` and `"match":"ski"` return no results

How can I fix that?

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html)

Comment: At Qbox we have done a couple of blog posts about this issue. One is pretty quick and easy: http://blog.qbox.io/quick-and-dirty-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-completion-suggest and the other is a bit more involved: http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams. Hope it helps. And I agree with the first comment, too (that's how I learned how to do it in the first place). :)

Comment: Thanks Sloan. That blog post was great, and worked like a charm.

Comment: @SloanAhrens the links are not opening.